# Problems forming Imagemagick commands using nodejs gm module

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, aws-lambda, graphicsmagick, gm

I am trying to run an imageMagick command on AWS Lambda and using the gm module. I keep getting an error no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544. I believe this error indicates that my syntax isn't correct for the command. I've tried many ways. I can run this command on the command line on my Linux system fine.

Here's the command. ([adapted from here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tidbits/image_info.php#gray_stats))

```
convert test.jpg -crop 120x120+300+300 -colorspace gray -format "%[fx:100*mean]%%" info:
```

Here's my function.

```
gm(imgobj,'test.jpg').command('convert')
    .in('-crop', '120x120+300+300','-colorspace','gray','-format','%[fx:100*mean]%%')
    .out('info:')
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
});
```

[gm nodejs module.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) is here.

SOLVED!

```
gm(imgobj,'test.jpg').command('convert')
    .in('-crop', '120x120+300+300')
    .in('-colorspace', 'gray')
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
        if(err) throw err;
        gm(buffer, 'test.jpg').identify({bufferStream: true, format:'%[fx:100*mean]'},function(err, data) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('identify',data);
        });
});
```

The documentations mentions this "GOTCHA":

> When working with input streams and any 'identify'operation (size,
>   format, etc), you must pass `{bufferStream: true}` if you also need to
>   convert (write() or stream()) the image afterwards (NOTE: this buffers
>   the readStream in memory!).

The documentation says to use: `gm().identify(format, callback)` and this seems to work for me without setting `bufferStream: true`. I suppose that is correct since I do not "need to stream the image afterwards."  However, for general knowledge, I looked at the source and figured out how to pass both params `{bufferStream: true, format:'%[fx:100*mean]'}` format being the [escape argument](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

Comment: Does it go through a shell? Try removing the `-format "..."` part to simplify and see if that is the problem. Try removing the `%%` part too.

Comment: The module does build out shell commands. Would be nice if there were a way to see the actual command - so may look into that next and get those on the console. The other information on this is that when I catch the output stream I'm getting image data when I am expecting to simply get a number.

Comment: Are you actually using **ImageMagick** and not **GraphicsMagick**?

Comment: Yes. I'm loading like `const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});` - my understanding is this loads imageMagick

Comment: I have another call `gm(imgobj).command('convert').in('-distort','ScaleRotateTranslate', angle.x +',' + angle.y + ' ' + angle.degree).toBuffer` this works just fine; on the same image I'm using as test data; so I know I'm good as far as platform. I think it's just something with this library. I have something else to try. Going to try doing the manipulation; hold it in memory and then get the info from it with seperate call.

Comment: Did you try removing the `-format "..."` like I suggested earlier?